# Salesforce email template access from Community

Tags: email-template, community-builder, partner-portal

Previously when I had this

```
EmailTemplate template=[select Id,subject,HtmlValue from EmailTemplate 
                    where DeveloperName='CS_New_Case_Notification_Assignment_Group'];
```

query in a trigger and it worked completely fine.

Now i have developed a trigger framework and the same query is in an apex class(handler) which is called in the trigger.

So when i log in the community from a portal user and create a record which fires this trigger its giving " System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject" error.

But the same piece of code snippet works when it is directly inside the trigger and not in any handler class.

**The portal user profile has access to those apex classes(handlers) been called.

Is there any permission issue for Email templates for portal users?

Comment: your apex class: with sharing, without sharing?

Comment: The apex class was with "with sharing".Its working now after changing it to "without sharing".

Thanks a lot @CROPREDY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, when portal/community users don't have access to a record, it is because the sharing model for the running user of the record in question does not permit access to the record.

Normally, one uses the `Setup | Security Controls | Sharing Settings` to define the sharing model. But not all objects can be managed this way (e.g. `EmailTemplate`).

- When [running in a trigger, the SOQL does not respect sharing rules](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23772/are-triggers-and-their-delegated-classes-or-batch-affected-by-sharing)
- When running in an Apex class, [the sharing rules as defined on the class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_keywords_sharing.htm?search_text=sharing) determine whether the SOQL executed in the class adheres to the sharing rules. Such sharing model may be inherited from a caller's class or defined explicitly on the class definition.

As such, for your class, you should be using `without sharing`. Use this sparingly to avoid creating security holes for any sensitive data.